# Qtranslate X: Show selector only if you have translated content

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

I don't want to use the normal Lang switcher, I just want to let the user know if that content is available in other languages.

Example: You are reading a page in English, and at the end of the article, something like: This article is also available in German and French.

I tried this one but didn't work - [Wordpress - Qtranslate to show only available languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101446/wordpress-qtranslate-to-show-only-available-languages)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What didn't work about this other solution?

Comment: A PHP error I can't find out why. It says Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
Am I writing it in a wrong place?

Comment: @LucasHaas Did you try the accepted answer with the other answer which corrected it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23663398/799845

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress - Qtranslate to show only available languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101446/wordpress-qtranslate-to-show-only-available-languages)